# UIBarButton Not does not appear on navigation bar - iOS

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am adding two `UIBarButtons` in my navigation bar. Surprisingly, left button works perfectly and appears on left side. But by using same method, right button does not appear. It appears while view is loading but then disappears.

Here is the code I am using:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];

UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"]
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cashcoin.png"]
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightRevealButtonItem;
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for gesture recognition.

Comment: Double check, whether cashcoin.png really exists and is included in the bundle (!). Just out of courisotiy I'd try swappint .leftBarButtonItem with .rightBarButtomIntem to see if it works on the other side. But I really bet it is caused by the image.

Comment: Image is already included and being used at many places. Swapped buttons but still same result. only left button is shown but not right

Comment: Frankly I don't know SWRevealViewController. Where exactly in relation to any call of the related [super method] is your code sniplet executed? And in which method?

Comment: SWReveal is custom controller. I am using it for left sliding menu. I am trying to have two menus on both sides, left and right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check your code again, You should set your bar items in `viewDidLoad`
- You might be setting `rightBarItem` to nil in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` as you mentioned that button appears and then disappear on screen loading.
- Swap buttons i.e left item to right and vice versa.

I hope your issue will be resolved.

Comment: that was plum.... I was setting it nil in viewDidAppear... you saved my day man...